# Apache Spark (Scala) - print 1 entry of an RDD / pairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, key-pair

When using an RDD I have grouped the items within the RDD by Key.

```
    val pairRDD = oldRDD.map(x => (x.user, x.product)).groupByKey
```

`pairRDD` is of type: `RDD(Int, Iterable[Int]))`

What I am having trouble with is simply accessing a particular element. What is the point of having a key when I can't seemingly access the item in the RDD by key?

At the minute I `filter` the RDD down to a single item, however I still have an RDD, and as such I have to do a `foreach` on the RDD to print it out:

```
    val userNumber10 = pairRDD.filter(_._1 == 10)
    userNumber10.foreach(x => println("user number = " + x._1))
```

Alternatively, I can `filter` the RDD and then `take(1)` which returns an Array of size 1:

```
    val userNumber10Array = pairRDD.filter(_._1 == 10).take(1)
```

Alternatively to that I can select the first element of that returned array:

```
    val userNumber10Array = pairRDD.filter(_._1 == 10).take(1)(0)
```

Which returns me the pair as required. But...
clearly, this is inconvenient and I would hazard a guess at saying that this is not how an RDD is meant to be used!

Why am I doing this you may ask! Well, the reason it's come about is because I simply wanted to "see" what was in my RDD for my own testing purposes. So, is there a way to access individual items in an RDD (more strictly a pairRDD) and if so, how? If not, what is the purpose of a pairRDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `lookup` function, which belongs to `PairRDDFunctions`. From the official documentation:

> Return the list of values in the RDD for key key. This operation is
>   done efficiently if the RDD has a known partitioner by only searching
>   the partition that the key maps to.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/core/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.html

And if you just want to see the contents of your RDD, you simply call `collect`.

Comment: Perfect, `lookup` works great. However, maybe this is a bug, but when I try and call `lookup` from the Console it says the method does not exist. Doing a Ctrl + Space and I can see the method is not visible (existent). But in the code (.scala file) it works fine. Any suggestions for this odd behaviour?

Comment: The `lookup` function and many others that operate on pair RDDs are available through an implicit conversion (check the link in my answer to `PairRDDFunctions`). So, properly speaking, the console may not be able to "infer" the conversion and only lists the RDD functions, and not the ones that are made available through the implicit conversions. This may apply for many operations, not only `lookup`.